# bitcoin-cli says transaction amount and balance are 0, but that's not the case

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, testnet, bitcoin-cli

I imported a few TestNet addresses and sent some funds to one of them. When I run

`bitcoin-cli getaccount mvKoQLrzovNbgALa2D7prh9pagd2QUKpWo`

it responds with the account I named it to.

I sent 1.1BTC to that address, as can be seen [here](https://testnet.blockchain.info/tx/3652238662b14e30a5b51d766fa7706af89d79625e73ccfdb8ec16645a1412d3) but when I run gettransaction it says amount: 0, but everything else looks correct. getbalance also returns 0. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "bitcoin-cli -testnet getreceivedbyaddress 'mvKoQLrzovNbgALa2D7prh9pagd2QUKpWo'" returns the correct amount, but balance of the whole wallet still says 0. I'm beyond confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to be that you are not on the testnet network. and i noticed that you're sending the commands with attaching -testnet

> bitcoin-cli -testnet getreceivedbyaddress 'mvKoQLrzovNbgALa2D7prh9pagd2QUKpWo'"

**To run Bitcoin on testNet**

Stop Bitcoin and open `~./bitcoin/bitcoin.conf` using any text editor.

and add `testnet=1` save and close.

try `bitcoin-cli listunspent 0 9999` you should see the transaction.

Anyway if you were already running it on testnet network

try the following command to get address balance

```
bitcoin-cli getbalance "" 0 true
```

**Arguments:**

1. "account"         (string, optional)
2. minconf           (numeric, optional, default=1) Only include transactions confirmed at least this many times.
3. include_watchonly (bool, optional, **default=false**) Also include balance in watch-only addresses.

Comment: Thank you so much, Adam! I was running on testnet, but my watchonly was equal to false. You're the man, dude!

Comment: Is there a list somewhere of all the bitcoin.conf options? I can't seem to find one

Comment: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin#Bitcoin.conf_Configuration_File. I believe it's not all the options but the most used ones.